# Bind Recursion DNS Server Returning Wildcard Address for Host Despite Exact Entry Existing in Zonefile on Hosts DNS Server

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, dns-zone, wildcard

I setup a bind server (version `BIND 9.18.16-1+ubuntu20.04.1+isc+1-Ubuntu` on `Ubuntu 20.04`), and this particular instance is setup as a recursion resolver with no forwarders.  When I dig one of my outside domains using this nameserver, it returns the wildcard address for the host from the dns server responsible for the host, but a `specific` host entry exists in the bind zonefile for that host, and this is the address that it should return.

For example, the domain `test.test.me` is setup with a zonefile similar to this (shortened and using sample IPs and hostnames) on server `1.1.1.1`

```
test.test.me.           IN A    1.1.1.1
*                       IN A    2.2.2.2
fun.test.test.me.       IN A    3.3.3.3
```

When I `dig fun.test.test.me @resolvesto4.4.4.4.com` my dns recursion server returns `2.2.2.2` rather than `3.3.3.3`.  Any idea why?  Is bind not working as expected?  Is there a bug in this version?

When I have bind use Google's DNS as a forwarder, it does return the correct response of `3.3.3.3`, so why doesn't my recursion setup without any forwarders return the wildcard value rather than what is expected?

If I remove the wildcard entry from the zone file, my dns recursion server will return the proper value.  So, it definitely seems to be something related to the wildcard entry... Is this a bug in the latest versions of bind?

Comment: show the zone file and bind9 config, please also comply with [ask]

Comment: @djdomi, it's setup exactly as my sample, and what part of how to ask am I not complying with?  The question is clear.

Comment: Im glad that you asked, take alook on this [checklist](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/6074/do-you-have-a-checklist-that-can-help-me-ask-a-better-question)